# Help solving for equivalent resistance

Tags: resistance

I'm trying to simplify this circuit but I'm not very sure about what the next step is. Something tells me that I could ignore R5, R6 and R7 and it would be the same but I'm not very sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image: Original circuit]

[image: Best attempt]

Edit: This is my new attempt but I'm not too sure about it.
[image: New best attempt]

Edit 2: Latest attempt
[image]

Comment: Is this homework? Normally people only provide hints to homework questions. Here is a hint for now. What you did on the whiteboard appears correct. Looking at the whiteboard do you see any more resistors in series or parallel that could be simplified?

Comment: @mkeith Yes, it is. I edited my original post to add what I think might be the answer but I'm not feeling too sure about it. Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: You are doing great. Nothing to be sorry about. But it seems like you dropped something, though. You combined R2 and R3 in parallel, but there was a wire (0 Ohm resistor) in parallel with the whole R5,R6,R7 series/parallel mix. You were right to wonder if R5, R6 and R7 are doing anything.

Comment: Is it not possible to simplify the entire circuit?

Comment: It is. If you look at your second picture, though, there is a wire shorting out R6+(R7*R5)/(R7+R5). In your third picture, at some point you replaced that wire with an open circuit. That step is a mistake. A wire is a short circuit. It is like a zero ohm resistor in parallel with R6 + (R7*R5)/(R7+R5). What is the resistance of Rx and Ry in parallel when Rx is 0 Ohms?

Comment: Yes you can simplify it, but follow your gut on R5,R6,R7.  The white board work is wrong in this regard.

Comment: I edited my post with another attempt, still not really sure about what I'm doing.

Comment: The last picture seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Much of this exercise involves identifying and simplifying circuit elements before combining them all into a solution. It is an important skill to learn.

Can you see that all three versions (below) are similar?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjbLno.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, I can see that they are. It looks like I can't understand what to do after this though, would you suggest something to study for me to be able to understand what to do in this situation?

Comment: Your **math** skill combining resistors in parallel & in series is excellent. But you're having trouble dealing with a short-circuit across \$ R_6 + \frac{R_5*R_7}{R_5+R_7}\$. Draw this short-circuit as a resistor having zero ohms - perhaps that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Your instinct with " Something tells me that I could..." is good. What is the resistance of the vertical path that connects R2 and R3 to R4. That path is in parallel with the R5, R6, R7 circuit.